# Modifying addresses in html file by inserting an additional folder layer

Tags: html, notepad++

I have an html file which has the code for a sidebar.

There are several hundred lines spread throughout the file of the form

```
<li><a href="A/B/C.html">text1</a></li>
<li><a href="A/B/D.html">text2</a></li>
<li><a href="A/B/E.html">text3</a></li>
```

What I would like to do is modify the text to insert an extra directory in each address, just before the .html file and with the same name as the html file. For example, the result would be to change the lines of text above to the following:

```
<li><a href="A/B/C/C.html">text1</a></li>
<li><a href="A/B/D/D.html">text2</a></li>
<li><a href="A/B/E/E.html">text3</a></li>
```

I installed notepad++ a few days ago, but have still not fully figured out what is possible. However, suggestions for any other way to efficiently do these text edits very welcome.

Comment: Do the files actually contain just A/B/C.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need regular expression replace in notepad++, open the find dialog

> Find a single char before '.html' string

find : `(.)\.html`

> Replace with the find repeated with a / inbetween

Replace with : `$1/$1.html`

Search Mode : `Regular Expression`

Note that above works only if the filename is single char, in case if your filename is multi-char, you need to use the following find expression instead

> Find max number of characters not containing / , just before .html

find : `([^/]+)\.html`

Comment: glad to help, its a nice gesture to upvote the helpful answer and accept it.

Comment: Had not noticed those possibilities - am a new comer to the forum.I did accept the the answer, but am a new comer to the forum and do not have enough reputation to upvote it.